# How to add pop-up functionality to Zendesk custom applications？

Tags: zendesk

I now want to implement the small functionality of pop-ups in my custom application for Zendesk. I want this pop-up to not just appear inside my embedded app, but in the middle of the entire page.

How do I do this, I don't see a solution in the Zendesk documentation.If anyone can help me, I would be very grateful